# Expand parameter pack in order

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates

I have a function that takes a tuple and I want to iterate over the tuple members in order. My current version is compiler dependent because it uses function parameters to unpack the tuple members (in `std::make_tuple()`).

I have build a simplified example of what I am doing:

```
template<typename T>
void* printMember(T const& d)
{
    std::cout << d << " ";
    return nullptr;
}
template<typename Members, std::size_t... Seq>
void printTuppleMembers(Members const& members, std::index_sequence<Seq...> const&)
{
    std::make_tuple(printMember(std::get<Seq>(member))...);
}
template<typename... Members>
void printTupple(std::tuple<Members...> const& members)
{
    printTuppleMembers(members, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Members)>());
}
```

I can not think of a way to force the calling of `printMember()` for each member of the tupple so that it happens for the members 0..n in the correct order.

I tried using initializer lists.

```
std::make_tuple({printMember(std::get<Seq>(member))...});
         //     ^                                     ^
```

But this did not compile.

It currently works on my system but I would like a generic solution that works on all systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pack expansion inside a braced initializer list is guaranteed left-to-right evaluation:

```
auto discard = {0, (printMember(std::get<Seq>(members)), 0)...};
(void)discard;
```

Comment: You are missing a `void` cast, or a `void()`, just in case `printMember` returns an evil type with an overloaded `operator,`: as `printMember` is looked up in an ADL enabled context, any member type could have a local overload, and you'd get strange side effects.  It seems prudent to avoid that.